# Looking for chrome script which can auto delete comments on FB ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am looking for a script which I can use on my browser. The script needs to check every 20 seconds for any new comments, when found should immediately delete the comments.

I am getting too many spam comments on my FB Ad post which is making a negative impact on my ad performance. Please suggest me such script.

Below anyone could suggest the below chrome extension, it's not working.

https://github.com/JosephDillman/Facebook-Comment-Cleaner-Chrome-Extension-

I tried ChatGpt, spent 3 hours following instructions given by the bot. Nothing worked. My technical knowledge is zero. Please help

Comment: `it's not working`  is a useless description of a problem ... what actually happens?

Comment: ChatGpt is worse than a parrot, at least a parrot knows what it is saying sometimes

Comment: I installed the chrome plugin & it's not working. It has not been updated since 2 years now. I want a working extention like the one I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: nobody is going write the code for you ... this site is for answering specific questions about code that you are writing ... `it's not working` is **not** the same thing as `nothing happens and no errors are generated`

Comment: "My technical knowledge is zero." - in that case, it is best to hire someone for this.